# Is there a "Not For Replication" equivalent in Sync Framework

Tags: sql, t-sql, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm looking for a way to prevent triggers from firing during a synchronization in Sync Framework 2.1.  This was a no brainer with the "Not For Replication" attribute when using MS SQL replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, there is none in the Sync Fx SDK. you can however programmatically disable the triggers (sending "DISABLE TRIGGER  ON ) before the sync and enabling it afterwards. please note though that the tracking tables will be out of sync with the base table (e.g., you may have deleted rows but the tracking doesnt have the tombstone records for it)